# Different features for different models

Tags: neural-networks, random-forest, accuracy, feature-engineering

Is it considered 'fair' to use different input features when comparing forecasting accuracy between models?

For example, adding feature x1, x2 and x3 into a random forest while adding x2, x3 and x4 into a mlp?
Are forecasting accuracy measures like MAE, RMSE and MAPE still valid?

Comment: You may view the models as incorporating the entire collection of features--the first just happens to ignore `x4` while the second ignores `x1`.  Does that answer your other questions?

Comment: yes, thank you!